# NameError: undefined local variable or method `logger'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging

When I run 'script/server' everything works fine, but when I run my unit tests (`rake test:units`), I get the error below, and am not sure how to solve this.

### Error

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `logger' for #<GiveawayEligibleMemberTest:0x10477dff8>
    /Users/kamilski81/Sites/pe/vitality_mall/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/test_process.rb:471:in `method_missing'
    /Users/kamilski81/Sites/pe/vitality_mall/lib/update_giveaway_eligible_members.rb:17:in `is_valid_checksum?'
    /Users/kamilski81/Sites/pe/vitality_mall/test/unit/giveaway_eligible_member_test.rb:26:in `test_that_checksum_is_valid'
    /Users/kamilski81/Sites/pe/vitality_mall/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:60:in `__send__'
    /Users/kamilski81/Sites/pe/vitality_mall/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:60:in `run'
```

I tried putting:

```
class Test::Unit::TestCase
  RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER = Logger.new(STDOUT)
  RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER.level = Logger::WARN

  logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
  logger.level = Logger::WARN
end
```

Here is the code that is using my logger:

```
def is_valid_checksum?(csv_arr)
  expected_row_count = csv_arr[0][3].to_i
  logger.debug "Expected record count: #{expected_row_count}"
  actual_row_count = csv_arr.nitems - 1
  logger.debug "Actual record count: #{actual_row_count}"
  checksum_valid = false
  if expected_row_count == actual_row_count
    logger.debug "Checksum is valid"
    checksum_valid = true
  end

  return checksum_valid
end
```

But this still does not solve the error

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can use the Rails logger outside of models and controllers:

```
Rails.logger.info "..."
```

[Source](http://jasonseifer.com/2009/08/10/using-the-rails-logger-outside-of-models-and-controllers)

Comment: I use whenever gem to schedule my rake task as cron task, this answer helped me to log logs to `log/cron.log`

Answer (score 6):

The `logger` method isn't available to test cases instance methods.

You have defined a local variable in your class definition but this isn't enough. The logger variable falls out of scope once the class is initialized. You may be looking for a class variable (`@@logger`). But a cleaner solution would be wrapping it in a method like this.

```
class Test::Unit::TestCase
  def logger
    RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER ||= Logger.new(STDOUT)
  end
end
```

Notice this code will use the default logger if it is available (which it should be). If this isn't desired, you can make your own just as easily.

```
def logger
  @logger ||= Logger.new(STDOUT)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER.debug the constant in your test case is_valid_checksum? not the variable logger(class level variable ) which cannot be used in a instance method.

I would suggest to wrap the code in a instance method something like

```
def logger
  logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
  logger.level = Logger::WARN
  logger
end
```

and then use logger

Comment: Your syntax highlighting is off. And you should probably use an instance variable to save the logger. Something like `@logger ||= Logger.new` that way the logger won't be re-initialized on every call.